# Joint probability of a minimum and maximum score after $n$ dice rolls

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, independence

An unbiased die is thrown $n$ times; let $M$ and $m$ denote the maximum and minimum points obtained respectively. Find $P\left( m=2, M=5 \right)$. (Hint: begin with $P\left (m\geq2, M\leq 5 \right)$.)

The question is from elementary probability theory (Kai Lai Chung)

Here is my thought process:

The minimum $m$ and maximum $M$ points obtained in $n$ throws are independent events. So:

$$ P(m\geq2, M\leq5) = P(m \geq 2)P(M\leq5)$$
$$ P(M\leq5) = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n $$
$$ P(m\geq2) = 1-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^n $$
$$P(m\geq2, M\leq5) = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n - \left(\frac{5}{9}\right)^n$$

under above conditions, $P(m=2, M=5)$ is just $\frac{1}{6}$ in all combinations. So:

$$ P(m=2, M=5) = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n - \frac{\left(\frac{5}{9}\right)^n}{6} $$

But the answer is $\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^n - 2\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^n + \left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^n$.

Can anyone help me figure out where I went wrong?

Comment: The minimum and the maximum are never independent events.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Uncool to post a possible answer because of the self-study tag?

Comment: I didn't think of that as a full answer, just a "try to put your mind here".  I will delete.  My apologies.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, based on the correct answer, I reversely think about this question. My though was following: the probability $2=< x =< 5$ was $(\frac{4}{6})^n$. there was another situation only appeared 3 and 4 whose probability was $ (\frac{2}{6})^n$.  The minus part in the answer suggest that this part was double counting. But I can not explain it.

Comment: @wikichung $\frac{4}{6}^n$ is the probability of rolling between a $2$ and $5$, $n$ times in a row.  If you do that, does that make $m=2$ and $M=5$?  If not, what quantity is $\frac{4}{6}^n$, in terms of $m, M$?

Comment: @jlimahaverford It contains some situations which do not meet the condition $m=2$ and $M=5$. Thanks for your reminding.

Comment: Can you write what $\frac{4}{6}^n$ equals in terms of $m, M$?  If this is to hard can you give me an example of an event counted by  $\frac{4}{6}^n$ which does not make $m=2, M=5.$

Comment: @MatthewDrury Matthew, I am so sorry... It was a complete misunderstanding. I wasn't criticizing your comment. All the contrary, I was asking you for guidance as to whether to post an answer I had typed or not (which is what I ultimately opted to do) given the self-study nature of the post. Your hint was great!

Comment: @AntoniParellada Ahh, I see.  No need to apologize, misunderstandings are a pretty inevitable consequence of communication!

Comment: @MatthewDrury Well, that's interesting. I can look at it, but it seems I can't undelete it (probably because you're the author deleting your own comment). What Matthew said was: $$\;$$ 
 
> *Here's where my mind goes. Try a special case, say $P(m=2,M=5)$. What values can you not roll? What values must you roll at least one of?*

Answer (score 1):

I'll post an "answer," mainly composed of wikichung's ideas.  We independently roll the unbiased die $n$ times obtaining $X_1, \dots, X_n$, with minimum value $m$ and maximum value $M$.  What is $P(m=2, M=5)$?  You noted that

$$
P(2 \leq X_i \leq 5; \forall i) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{4}{6} = \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^n.
$$
Now how does this relate to $P(m=2, M=5)$?  It is two big!  For example we are counting events for which $m \neq 2$, such as $(5, 5, \dots, 5)$.  However, if for each $i$, $2 \leq X_i \leq 5$, then $m \geq 2$ and $M \leq 5$.  So we have determined that,

$$
P(m \geq 2, M \leq 5) = \frac{4}{6}.
$$

By the same logic for any $a \leq b$:

$$
P(m \geq a, M \leq b) = \frac{b-a+1}{6}.
$$

So I will leave the last question to you.  How can we rewrite $P(m=2, M=5)$ by adding and subtracting terms of the form $P(m\geq a , M\leq b)?$  This is where you will need inclusion/exclusion.

**edit** - Additional Information

Define $S(m,M) = |\{$sequences with min $=m$ and max $=M\}|$, and $T(m,M) = |\{$sequences with min $\geq m$ and max $\leq M\}|$.  Then we have:

$$
S(2,5) = T(2,5) - T(3,5) - t(2,4) + ?.
$$

There are some sequences counted by $T(2,5)$, which are not counted by $S(2,5)$, but which were *doubly* undone with the two negative terms.  What are they?

Comment: @jlimahaverford $(\frac{2}{6})^n$ stands for {2,2,2,…,5,5,5…}, right?

Comment: @wikichung It could, but that is not my interpretation of the answer.  JohnK I don't quite understand what you mean by endpoints.  I'll edit my answer with my interpretation.

Comment: I meant the double-counting but you got it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please find the answer attached in the image below.